# How to edit beginning and ending of file with sed

Tags: sed

I'm trying to add array brackets at the beginning and end of a file using `sed` (after first removing the trailing comma at the end of the file) to put all the content of the file in an array.  I'm first using this sed command to remove the last comma from a file

```
sed '$ s/,$//' "$path"
```

After that, I'm using the middle command below to add array brackets at beginning and ending of file

```
 sed '$ s/,$//' "$path" |   sed 's/^.*$/[&]/' | tee $filename
```

This `sed 's/^.*$/[&]/'` was supposed to match everything (from beginning to end `^$`) and then put brackets around the whole match `[&]` (i.e. as if to make it into an array), but it instead put array brackets around the beginning and end of each line.

Question, how to edit the beginning and ending of a file with sed?

whole script

```
for path in dirname/* do
   name="${path##*/}"
   sed '$ s/,$//' "$path" | sed 's/^.*$/[&]/' | tee "newdir/$name"
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sed is an editor that works line by line, so the command `sed 's/^.*$/[&]/'` would add brackets to *every* line. If you want to edit just the beginning and end of a file you need to put line numbers in front of the substitutions (`$` stands for the last line):

```
sed -e '1 s/^/[/' -e '$ s/$/]/'
```

Since you already have a command that removes trailing `,`'s you could combine it with the aforementioned substitutions. Your command line would then look like this:

```
sed -e '1 s/^/[/' -e '$ s/,*$/]/' "$path" | tee $filename
```

Comment: ok,  thank you. I just tested it and the output is not what I expected. Maybe my question wasn't clear.  The output I'm getting is square brackets at the beginning and end of each line in the file. If a file has multiple lines, it's like having an array on each line. However, I want the whole file to be in an array, i.e. one square bracket at beginning, one closing bracket at end. That's why I tried to match `^.*$` everything... Is sed only a line editor?  Is there a way to match the whole file ?

Comment: oh, i see, sed only edits line by line...guess I'm using the wrong tool. I'll accept your answer anyways since it answers the question.. If you can tell me where to look in comment, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: ok, nice, thank you  that seems to work when I test it, but note that your closing square bracket seems to be facing wrong way for it to close an array

Comment: @Leahcim Great, I've also edited my answer and will clean up my comments later. Have a nice day.